# Social-feed - API

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api, twitter

I am begining to work with API's and am trying to get a working example of the Social-Feed API (https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed) on a template HTML.

I have installed bower as instructed in the Github.

I have the dependency scripts loading in just before the closing body tag, A div container for the social feed script and the social feed script within that div.

I am unsure as to why the API is not working. here is a link to the code I am using: https://codeshare.io/5DAwel

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put those links to the scripts into the 'head /head' area of your side. 
Compare your source code with the source of the demo page: https://pavelk2.github.io/social-feed-example/

Comment: I have compared the 2, and I can see the difference now however it still does not answer my question as I cannot get the API working, thanks though